# Communication between Photon Cloud game and web server

Tags: unity, networking, multiplayer, unity-networking, photon

I am creating a multiplayer game using Photon Cloud (Photon Unity Network). For storage of player data (profile, inventory, achievments) I use web server (asp.net mvc & sql server). How to organize the communication between the game client and the web server? I see two ways:

1. Use WWW class and send requests direct to web server:

   ```
   var www = new WWW("http://mygame.com/api/user.get?id=1");
   // Each time creates a new connection to the web server
   ```
2. Use Photon Cloud Webhooks and send requests through Photon servers:

   ```
   PhotonNetwork.WebRpc("user.get?id=1");
   // Photon Servers play a Proxy or Relay role between client and web server
   ```

   — http://doc.photonengine.com/en/realtime/current/reference/webrpc

Which way do you recommend? The first way is simple but each time creates a new connection to the web server. The second way use one persistent connection between client and Photon server but there is a delay between connecting the Photon server to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of advantages of the use of Photon's WebRPCs (compared to direct client to web server HTTP requests) at this [link](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/realtime/current/reference/webrpc#why_choose_webrpc).

I think that if you don't need any of those then you shouldn't use it and you can find better alternatives than Unity's WWW.